# How to design a JHipster 'job'?

Tags: jhipster

I hava a node api that I run and scale in AWS with ECS Fargate. It has both web clients and server side clients .
One of the server side clients is another separate 'scheduled' node app that starts up runs a job and then dies (it does not need to scale or be long lived). When it runs it uses the client credentials flow to make a call in to the other scaled node app.

I am trying to work out how I could do the equivalent of this with Jhipster in Heroku. Obviously I would run my api in a scaled fashion with multiple dynos.. but what about the other job that I need to wake up do some work and then die ? I guess I would just create another jhipster app without a UI.. but how to deploy it etc?

I realise I can use Spring @scheduled features but I def do not want to have to coordinate that in a situation where multiple instances are running

Comment: Why don't you want to coordinate between your multiple instances? There are many ways to do it: Quartz clustering, Hazelcast lock, database lock, ... It depends on whether your instances know each other, are you using Eureka?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Scheduler code within an App with multiple instances with multiple JVMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740830/spring-scheduler-code-within-an-app-with-multiple-instances-with-multiple-jvms)

Comment: had thought it was just general bad practice to introduce a job into an application that runs in a sclaed fashion . i.e. having to elect a 'leader' instance to only run the jobs etc. I am not using eureka as its just a monolith. I know I could use a database lock etc but those all just add complexity I thought. Whats the suggested way to do it in a scaled monolith ?

Comment: Running a job in a cluster does not require electing a leader.The question I linked gives alternatives. Your question is tagged only JHipster, what you describe seems more about spring boot + heroku. Anyway, scaling a monolith is more complex than putting a load balancer in front of multiple instances. As soon as you have caching, you must use clustering like Hazelcast or you will have stale data. Instance discovery using Eureka, Consul is not always required if your distributed cache has some support for it.

Comment: i dont have caching.. keeping it simple. I just want the job to run on one of the instances without having to write a whole load of complex code. Is there an example anywhere on how I could use Quartz in spring to have a job run on only one instance ?